# Resize Parent view dynamically when Child view is added out of bound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

```
UIView *parentView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]];
UIView *childView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[CGRectMake(0,120,100,100)]];
[parentView addSubview:childView];
```

The code above stating childView is added into parentView at a location outside of parentView bound. Is there anyway i can resize parentView so that the childView is no longer out of bound? I want to do this dynamically. Is there any auto function available, or I have to do it manually by calculating the overall size.

Another question is, before the resizing of parentView to fit in childView, it seems that the childView is added at (0,100) instead of (0,120) of parentView, even though I set [parentView setClipsToBounds:NO];

Answer (score 0):

you can resize the parent view according to the child view frame

```
UIView *parentView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]];
UIView *childView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[CGRectMake(0,0,0,120)]];
[parentView addSubview:childView];

parentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,childView.frame.size.width,childView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: sorry i made a typo on my question, i edited my question. do suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If AutoLayout is an option for you I would recommend looking into **intrinsic content size**. You can set the constraints so that the parent view will resize according to the content (childView) in Interface Builder. There is a very good tutorial on AutoLayout on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: sorry i made a typo on my question, i edited my question. do suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UIView and override the addSubView method, in your addSubView override implementation you can check the size of the subview being added if needed and resize the current view.

```
@implementation CustomView

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {

  if(!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.view.size, view.size)) { // Sizes don't match

    // resize self.view here

  }
}

@end
```